# Implementing search on a given list of item?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Assume we have been given detail of an object `number, name, manufacturing date, price,`
`weight` and there are many objects.
I have to implement a search operation which is able to search the items on the basis
of multiple conditions, for example, search the item whose manufacturing
date is before `11 2020` and `price < 400`(compare only price and date) or we have to compare(only price and weight) `price is > 300` and `weight > 30` . 
If no item is found suitable, the result of the search should inform about it and if
multiple items follow the condition, they must be displayed in an ordered
way decided by the programmer (clearly mention the ordering criterion).

I tried using the structure of the array but I am stuck in performing any two searches out of six.

Comment: Post some code , also from what I understand you already have 6 search you just looking for a way to implement search with multiple conditions ?

Comment: Build a *kd-tree* and visit both children if a given parameter is not a search criterion.

Answer (score 0):

For searching the items:

Firstly, declare a counter variable:

```
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ITEMS; i++) {
    if (itemPrice[i] < 400 || itemPrice[i] > 300 && itemWeight[i] > 30 && manfDate[i] < 112020) {
        // cout for itemsPrice[i], itemWeight[i] and manfDate[i]
        counter++;
    }
}

if (counter == 0) {
    std::cout << "No Items Found." << std::endl;
}
```

Suppose there are 10 items given and their:

- Price is lesser than 400 and greater than 300
- Weight's more than 30 KG/LB
- Manufacture date's within 11200

It'll only show the data which are `TRUE` conditioned. Also notice that the counter variable is only used for verifying if the value isn't zero (no items found condition).